# MPU9255 without lib on STM32

Tags: stm32, i2c, keil, hal-library

I have a code on Arduino to read the data from MPU9255 with no libraries, using it direct through I2C. I am trying to do the same on Keil uVision with Bluepill, just to learn how to use I2C with HAL Drivers.

I don't know What I am doing wrong, here is the code:

```
uint8_t adressMPU = 0x68;
uint8_t i2cData;
uint8_t* receive_buffer = 0;

i2cData = 0x6B;

HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, adressMPU, &i2cData, 1, 100 );  //Starts MPU
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, adressMPU, 0, 1, 100 );
while (1)
{       
    i2cData = 0x43; //adress of the register to read Accelerometer x axis
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, adressMPU, &i2cData, 1, 100 ); //set the register address

    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, adressMPU, receive_buffer, 2, 100); request 2 bytes from the register
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,receive_buffer,sizeof(receive_buffer),100); // send it to serial port

    HAL_Delay(500); 
}
```

My code in Arduino that is working:

```
Wire.begin();                 //inicia I2C
Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);  //Inicia transmissão para o endereço do MPU
Wire.write(0x6B);             

Wire.write(0); 
Wire.endTransmission(true);

Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);      //transmite
Wire.write(0x43);                 // Endereço registrador do Gyro
Wire.endTransmission(false);     //Finaliza transmissão
Wire.requestFrom(MPU,6,true);   //requisita 6 bytes  
mediaGyroX += Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  //GYRO EIXO X
```

Surely I am doing something wrong, but I can't see the error. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You probably need to send the 0x6B followed by 0x00 in a single HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit() call. Something like `uint8_t i2cData[2] = {0x6B, 0x00}; HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, adressMPU, &i2cData, 2, 100 );`

Comment: I have tried, but does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For STM32 HAL define the slave address as `uint8_t adressMPU = (0x68<<1);`, because if you check the register description:

[image]

in 7 bit addressing mode actually [7:1] bits of the I2C CR2 register are used **but** HAL sets the address field as follows:

```
tmpreg |= (uint32_t)(((uint32_t)DevAddress & I2C_CR2_SADD) | (((uint32_t)Size << 16 ) & I2C_CR2_NBYTES) | \
            (uint32_t)Mode | (uint32_t)Request);

/* update CR2 register */
hi2c->Instance->CR2 = tmpreg;
```

(`I2C_CR2_SADD` is `0x3FF` which actually just masks the first 10 bits.) So the point is that HAL will set the 7 bit address mistakenly on [6:0] bits of the register if you do not shift to left by one manually.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see the mistake! I am receiving garbage ow on the bus, I will try to figure out why

Comment: @VincíciusJeanFerreira a logic analyzer can be useful also this HAL code is not from the latest version so you should check the actual one in your project. Just to be sure.

Comment: Your receive_buffer logic is wrong that is why you see garbage. It is a pointer to nowhere (no memory allocated) yet you try to receive two bytes with it. And then when sending on serial `sizeof(receive_buffer)` will return the size of the pointer. Define `receive_buffer` as `uint8_t receive_buffer[2]` instead.

Comment: I post my new code in the comment below