# How to interpret the values sent by an MPU-9255?

Tags: stm32, i2c, keil

Well, I am using this holiday in Brazil to improve my skills in C. I have learned how to use I2C and how to communicate with the MPU9255 (with help from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/355747/38335) question). The last trouble I am facing is that the sensor is returning wrong values. The value returned is floating from 0 to 65000, but it is not linear.

I think that is because I am making some confusion on the data types or bytes merge on my code. Can someone help me revising my code?

```
    uint8_t Test[] = "\n AccelX: \n";
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,Test,sizeof(Test),100);

    //SET X_HIGH REGISTER ADDRESS 
    i2cData = 0x3B;
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, adressMPU, &i2cData, 1, 100);

    //REQUEST 6 BYTES OF DATA (ACCEL X, Y AND Z)
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, adressMPU, receive_buffer, 6, 100); 

    AccelX = (char)receive_buffer[0]<<8 | (char)receive_buffer[1];
    AccelY = (char)receive_buffer[2]<<8 | (char)receive_buffer[3];
    AccelZ = (char)receive_buffer[4]<<8 | (char)receive_buffer[5];

    //PRINTA NA SERIAL 1
    len = sprintf(buffer, " %i\r\n", AccelX); //sprintf will return the length of 'buffer'  
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)buffer, len, 1000);  

    HAL_Delay(500);
```

---

Update:

I just noted one thing: from 0 to 16768, the sensor measurements are right, but when I upside the axis, the sensor goes from 65536 to ~49000 when should be from 0 to -16768. Surely is a conversion error, but I still not can see where exactly is the error.

Comment: So I'm assuming that when you compile the code, there are no errors or warnings? It's just not working the way you need it to? Have you debugged your code step by step? Learning how to program is not about learning the language, but rather learning how to solve problems and utilize algorithms. Try debugging your code step by step. Thankfully this isn't a long code so it won't take too long. See the interactions of your code when you perform it step by step.

Comment: Do you mean using debug and adding break points in the code?

Comment: I assume there is a lot more code, somewhere.

Comment: Debugging and Break Points are an essential part of developing working code, I would read up on that for your particular IDE.

Comment: The code is short, but I just noted one thing: from 0 to 16768, the sensor measurements are right, but when I upside the axis, the sensor goes from 65536 to ~49000 when should be from 0 to -16768. Surely is a conversion error, but I still not can see where exactly is the error

Comment: The problem is on the negative part. This should occurs because the function reads the bytes as unsigned char. Someone knows how I can solve this?

Comment: What is the type of `AccelX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPU-9255 is giving you a 16-bit, signed integer. Your code is interpreting it as unsigned.

An unsigned, 16-bit number can represent values from 0 to 65535. A signed 16-bit number represents -32768 to +32767.

Here is an 8-bit example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two's_complement):

[image: SignedUnsigned]

To make the conversion, first look at the high bit. If it is \$0\$, then no conversion is necessary. If it is \$1\$, then \$signed = (unsigned - 2^N)\$, where \$N\$ is the number of bits. Sixteen, in your case.

Here is a simple method for 16 bits:

```
uint16_t unsignedAccelX;
int16_t signedAccelX;

if (unsignedAccelX < 32768)
{
    signedAccelX = unsignedAccelX;
}
else
{
    signedAccelX = unsignedAccelX - 65536;
}
```

There are many more elegant and/or efficient ways of doing this. There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8317295/3380131).

Good luck!

Comment: I have solved this problema exactly this way hahaha Today I will looko for  more eficcient way